# Change state using componentDidUpdate()

Tags: reactjs

Hi i'm trying to change a state using componentDidUpdate() but I get an infinite loop.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    if (prevState.selectedOption1 !== this.state.selectedOption1) {
        this.setState({ disabled2: false });
    }
}
```

I can´t figure it out

Comment: The documentation for [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) should sort you out, but TLDR: the previous state is the second parameter not the first i.e. `componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) function uses 3 parameters:

1. previous properties
2. previous state
3. snapshot (for when `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()` is used.

You are treating the first parameter as previous state, which it is not, this results in your condition always being true and creating your infinite loop as setState is continually called.

To fix the issue correctly use the parameters of `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(
    prevProps, // This is the previous properties 
    prevState // This is the previous state.
) {
    if (prevState.selectedOption1 !== this.state.selectedOption1) {
        this.setState({ disabled2: false });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally understand. It's necesary to pass both parameters. Use it or not.

Comment: Yeah you have to define all preceding (before) parameters but all proceeding (after) parameters can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the state, the component updates.

Thus, if you change state state when the component updates then you get your infinite loop.

If you insist on keeping this behavior then you might want to add a boolean check to your state.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: They have a boolean check to stop infinite loops, the issue is that they are treating the previous props as the previous state which results in their check failing.

Comment: Could you show me that in code?